# Count to 100 using Javascript (in a div)

Tags: javascript, html

I wanne count to 100 in a div only using javascript. Why does only comes the last number.

Here is my code:

```js
function test() {
 for (var x = 1; x < 101; x++) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (x + "<br />");
 }
}function leer() {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Delete"

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="function.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="test()">100</button>
<button type="button" onclick="leer()">Delete</button>
<div id="demo">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += (x + "<br />");`  this line

```js
function test() {
 for (var x = 1; x < 101; x++) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += (x + "<br />");
 }
}function leer() {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Delete"

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="function.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="test()">100</button>
<button type="button" onclick="leer()">Delete</button>
<div id="demo">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a pointer, if questions are this basic, its better to comment as OP can then choose to remove the post. Also, you should look for similar posts and share their link in comment section until you have right to close yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Because the keep overriding the contents of the div with id "demo" by using innerHTML. You need to append the new number.

Please see this example (I updated your code).

```js
function test() {
 for (var x = 1; x < 101; x++) {
        var current_contents = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = current_contents  + (x + "<br />");
 }
}function leer() {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Delete"

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="function.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="test()">100</button>
<button type="button" onclick="leer()">Delete</button>
<div id="demo">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Indeed, using the += operator is even better, like Saba Tandashvili pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Because it happens so fast that you only see the last number. Do something like this:

```js
var _counter = 1;
    var _timer = null;
    function test() {       
        _counter = 1;
        _timer = setInterval(function(){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (_counter + "<br />");
            _counter++;
            if(_counter > 100) clearInterval(_timer);
        }, 1000);
    }
    
    function leer() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Delete"
    
    }
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<button onclick="test();">Count</button>
<button onclick="leer();">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.append` instead of `.innerHTML`